# Qt C++ - displaying the links in QText Browser

Tags: c++, qt

Right now I am displaying the result in `QTextBrowser`. Results will be something like `/home/User/`, `/media/Arena/` etc i.e path to different folders. Now I want to open the folder in a window by clicking on this result which is displayed in `QTextBrowser`. But I have no ideas how to do that. So can anyone let me know how to do it.

Thanx in advance.

**P.S.** I am using QtCreator & see the image http://i53.tinypic.com/qyxp1s.png.

Answer (score 1):

can you insert html rather than plain text into the QTextBrowser widget?  then you can use a URL to describe the paths.

Answer (score 1):

BasementCat's right. You can use `setHtml` QTextBrowser's method to set HTML into the widget. You'll then probably need to call `setOpenLinks(false)` to disable default behavior and connect custom slot to widget's `anchorClicked(QUrl const&)` signal to handle links.